# A method was called at unexpected time in TCP read request

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

```
StreamSocket _connection = AsyncCreateConnection(); // In constructor

private async void receive(){
DataReader reader = new DataReader(_connection.InputStream);
DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(_connection.OutputStream);

try
        {
            reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint)); // <<--  Explosion
            if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
            {
                return;
            }

            // Read the string.
            uint stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
            uint actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLength);
            if (stringLength != actualStringLength)
            {
                return;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadString(actualStringLength));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
}
```

Been getting this error all afternoon. Asynchrony of creating the connection should be finished when the receive method is called.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is saying that you are using the output of the `async` call before it's ready.

I believe your connection is not ready, maybe you should `await` connection also.

since constructor cannot be `async` you'll need to call it from another function.

```
StreamSocket _connection = await AsyncCreateConnection();
```